# How wal logs work in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.3

I have to do a point in time recovery in postgres should i have all the wal logs that are generated or is it fine to have few recent wal log files  ? I tried recovery but I'm not sure if all the files are recovered

Comment: You need all WALs generated between your [recovery target](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-target-settings.html#RECOVERY-TARGET-TIME) and the start of the preceding [base backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP).

Comment: So not all the wal files are required right ?  Is it fine if i have one week wal log files?

Comment: It depends on what your "point in time" is, and when your last base backup was taken.

Comment: hi nick, can you please elaborate

Comment: Like I said, you need every WAL generated in between your last backup and the point in time you're trying to recover to. If your last backup was a month ago and your PITR target is yesterday, then a week's worth of WAL files definitely isn't going to cover it.